# How do I localise my message when gathering consent with Google Founding Choices for GDPR in the EEA?

Tags: mobile, localization, admob, gdprconsentform, iab

In order to be GDPR compliant and work with Admob mediation (in **Europe**), I need to implement a consent management platform (CMP) in my mobile apps (iOS and Android).

Here is the complete list of TCF/IAB compliant CPMs: https://iabeurope.eu/cmp-list/. According to me, [Google Founding Choices](https://fundingchoices.google.com/) seems to be a good solution. Reason? It's free.

After playing a bit with the new Founding Choices console, it seems that it is possible to create messages in different languages and to trigger them in the app to collect user consent, which is good. Nevertheless, **only one message can be active at the time** (!?)

As you can see on the image below (this is screenshot of my Google Funding Choices console), I duplicated the message in 3 different languages but only one can be active at the time, so I do not understand...

[image]

If you have any clue on how to localise the message based on the locale of the user device, it would be helpful :-)

Thanks!

Comment: I think that Google needs to make changes. I was thinking the same and now I only display the English consent form. Nevertheless when people do not consent ads are not delivered to my app and I get IAB TCF Error 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since December 2020, it is possible to localise a message with Funding Choices. An update of the SDK may be needed, but that functionality in now available.

Comment: Can you tel me how? If i publish the dutch language message, the engilsh version is made inactive.

Comment: Lozalization is possible for apps see https://support.google.com/fundingchoices/answer/9805123?hl=en . I do not have any success for site localization.